# 502 Bad gateway error when using nginx reverse proxy with docker compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, backend

I'm encountering a 502 Bad Gateway error when attempting to access my services through a Docker Compose setup with Nginx acting as a reverse proxy. Here's a simplified version of my configuration:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/nginx-reverse-proxy/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./apps/nginx-reverse-proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - backend-network

  auth-service:
    container_name: "auth-service"
    build:
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth/Dockerfile
      context: .
    environment:
      - CLIENT_URL=${CLIENT_URL}
      # ... other environment variables
    networks:
      - backend-network

  mail-service:
    container_name: "mail-service"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/mail-service/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - CLIENT_URL=${CLIENT_URL}
      # ... other environment variables
      - TEMP=/app/apps/mail-service/src/temp/
    networks:
      - backend-network

networks:
  backend-network:
```

In this configuration , it should route the request to either of the service depending on the route of port 8080 but i am encountering connection refused while connecting to upstream on both of the routes .
nginx configuration.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/xml application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data;
    gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;

    upstream backend {
        server mail-service:3000;
        server auth-service:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name backend;

        location /api/v1/mail/ {
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://mail-service:3000;
        }

        location /api/v1/user/ {
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://auth-service:4000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your error log here?

Comment: The containers are starting up without any problem but i on sending a request i am facing this error [error] 29#29: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: backend, request: "POST /api/v1/user/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.20.0.4:4000/api/v1/user/", host: "localhost:8080"

Comment: As it shows failed to connect to the upstream, check the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that upstream servers were refusing the request because they were listening on their own localhost. Setting the IP to 0.0.0.0 will allow the connection to be established from the reverse proxy. This has fixed the issue on my end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).